# Save ggplots in one PDF with equal tick distance?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

I want to save multiple ggplots in one PDF file. I am creating them in a loop, storing them in a list and then saving them by using [ggsaves marrangeGrob function](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gridExtra/vignettes/arrangeGrob.html) like this:

```
ggsave(filename = "myfile", marrangeGrob(grobs = plot_list, nrow = 1, ncol = 1), width = 30, height = 10, limitsize = FALSE)
```

The problem I have now is that the plots contain different amounts of data. One plot can have 10 ticks on the y axis, while one plot can have 40. Same goes for the x axis. But I want the distance of the tick marks to be equally for a better comparison.

This is what it looks so far:

[image: plot with 12 ticks on y axis with larger tick distance]

[image: plot with about 40 ticks on y axis with smaller tick distance]

I know that I can scale the PDF size so that it would match the amount of ticks and with this create an equal distance between them, but I do not know how to do so when I store them in one single file.

One single PDF file with different pages it not completely mandatory, but I need a fast and easy way to compare a lot of plots with each other (there one PDF file is a little handier I guess).

Comment: See `scale_x_continuous()` . It's `breaks` argument allows you to specify ticks.

Comment: If you simply plot the graphs (ggplot()), in a Rmarkdown doc (https://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/lesson-1.html) you will get what you're looking for.

Comment: Here is a bunch of ggplot properties, including manipulating the axis.  http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/Axes_(ggplot2)/

Comment: Adding both `scale_x_continuous()` and `coord_fixed()` did the trick for me, thank you @Rohit and @Christoffer Sannes